# How to “require” an es6 “import”?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I'm working on a node app that uses node `v14.16.0`:

- It uses **lots** of `require` statements *(common js)*
- I want to use the latest version of [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch) but it's now an es6 module
- Node is insisting I use an `import` statement
- When I do, I get `Cannot use import statement outside a module` error

Is there a simple way to **require** an es6 module? or am I forced to upgrade an entire app?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#:~:text=CommonJS,published%20for%20v2. I found this now. Just switch to `axios` or `got`. Or upgrade to node 18.x since there's native fetch now.

Comment: I can't switch to another library because the project I'm working on depends on `fetch.Response`... I've tried your other suggestion, but it does not work :'(

Comment: Try this: `const nodeFetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));` if it doesn't work, see below

Comment: I found a `cjs` wrapper for node-fetch also that you can use instead. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch-commonjs. Or you can use `esm-hook` https://github.com/alex-kinokon/esm-hook

Comment: Thanks @joel, I was able to use the`cjs` wrapper - still having a few issues with it, but node is no longer complaining... Not tried `esm-hook` yet, will report back

Comment: `ems-hook` does not work, node complains of `Cannot find module 'node:http'`

Comment: Is there a reason for not running the LTS version of node? Node 14 reaches end of life in two months. https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule

Comment: Only that its a massive refactor we don’t have the capacity for

Comment: 14-16 is a relatively small change. Takes ~20min to do. (We have ~400k lines in our repo). Run `nvm install 16.18.1` and see if it all just doesn't work out of the box 

Comment: I just cant bring myself to do this in a production app.. Madness we're forced to upgrade an entire app to use one lib

Comment: There's nothing that's been deprecated. Also, there is a cjs-version still being maintained. Just use that one

Comment: I followed your advice and switching the entire app to use `import`, painful but solves the problem... I'll leave this open as I'd still like to know if there is a way to require and import

Comment: For the future, there's a tool that does the switch automatically for the most part: https://github.com/wessberg/cjstoesm

Comment: "*I'd still like to know if there is a way to require and import*" - to that, there's no solution. They are funamentally different. ESM are async and cjs is synchronous.